# My Variable will not change out side the definition

Tags: python, tkinter, output

I wrote my first py code. This code to create a lotto number generator.The problem is that my variable `nums` will not change. Please help me.
I understand this is not as good as it can be so please tell me how to improve, any comments will be appreciated.I wanted the random numbers to come up in the ladle so i could press the submit button and 5 new numbers to come up.The problem is my veritable "nums" wont change.Thank you for helping.

```
import random
from tkinter import *

#TK()

window = Tk()
window.title("Lottery Nummber Generator")

#Def Click

def click():
        global nums
        global numsgen
        numsgen = random.sample(range(1, 49), 5)
        nums = " ".join(str(x) for x in  numsgen)
        print(nums)

numsgen = random.sample(range(1, 49), 5)
nums = " ".join(str(x) for x in  numsgen)

#Fake just to make it look nice 

Label(window,text="").grid(row=1, column=0,sticky=W)
Label(window,text="").grid(row=2, column=1,sticky=W)
Label(window,text="").grid(row=2, column=3,sticky=W)


#Submit button

Button(window, text="Submit", width=5,command=click).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)

#Label

group = LabelFrame(window, text="Lottery Numbers:", padx=5, pady=5,fg="dark orange")
group.pack(padx=10, pady=10,)
group.grid(row=2, column=1,sticky=W)
w = Label(group, text=nums)
w.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Question will be equally visible even if you use a smaller font size.

Comment: It really works fine. Why did you conclude that it didnt work?

Comment: I wanted the random numbers to come up in the ladle so i could press the submit button and 5 new numbers to come up.The problem is my veritable "nums" wont change.Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

To get a label to update, you must do one of two things:

1. Associate a `StringVar` with the label. When you update the variable (via its `set` method), any labels associated with it will automatically change. This is a great solution if more than one widget needs to display the same value.
2. Directly configure the label. This requires that you save a reference to the widget(s) so that you can later reconfigure them. For example, you could put `w.configure(text=nums)` in your `click` function. This solution is a bit simpler than using a `StringVar`, simply because it requires one less object.

Comment: Thank you so much but i'm still unsure on how to use your method.I understand using StringVar but i'm unsure on how to implement it and I was using your example of using `w.configure(text=nums)`would you mind showing me how you would implement it into this code.Thank you so very much.